# Local notifications sent to background works in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, local, simulator

In the simulator I'm able to get the exact result I want: When I trigger a notification and my simulator phone is locked, then the notification gets pushed to the watch.

This used to work on device (my iPhone 6 on iOS 9.1 and Watch on watchOS 2.0). For some reason it stopped working and I don't know how to debug the problem.

So on device, I make sure that the app is in background by going to home screen and locking the phone and making sure my watch is asleep. When the notification is triggered, nothing happens. When I open up the app, that's when the notifications finally gets triggered. I.E. if I trigger 3 notifications, none of them register until I open the app back into foreground. This is not how it works in simulator (simulator has correct behavior described above).

The notification is triggered by me changing a text object that is stored in my Firebase db. The change calls the sendNotification function. Again, this works perfectly fine in the simulator and used to work on device but for some reason doesn't work anymore.

In app delegate I have:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil))

    // Setting up Local Notification
    let assistAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    assistAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    assistAction.identifier = categoryID
    assistAction.title = "Assist"
    assistAction.authenticationRequired = false
    assistAction.destructive = false

    // Category
    let assistCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    assistCategory.identifier = categoryID
    assistCategory.setActions([assistAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)

    // Only way to get this to work with parameter
    let categories = NSSet(object: assistCategory)

    // Settings
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: categories as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    //        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()


    return true
}
```

Then in my view controller I have:

```
func sendNotification(customerName: String, helpText: String) {
    // Local Notification
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "\(customerName) \(helpText)"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.fireDate = NSDate()
    notification.category = categoryID
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
    print("Sent notification");
}
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I did! Just answered my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulator seems to work differently than device. It's weird that simulator local notifications was acting like remote push notifications.

I ended up giving up on trying to make local notifications show up while app is in background on device because I've learned that that is not the expected behavior.

The correct solution is to just set up remote push notification, which I used Parse to do. And now it's working as expected. I have a web server that uses the Parse REST API to send a POST request to Parse and my iOS app is then set up to receive remote push notifications which now show up on my watch when my phone is locked.